# Use EXTRACT(Keys) or other method to get a Nodes properties as key:value pairing with Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use a cypher query to return results in a format that I can use with D3. What I have below is working fine but I want to be able to include the properties of the nodes as "key:value" pairs directly after the labels are printed out. I can't explicitly code this because different nodes can have different properties e.g. I can't just add (prop1: l1.prop1, prop2: l1.prop2 .....).

```
MATCH (l0) -[r]-> (l1)
WHERE ID(l0) = #
RETURN 
    [
        {
            type: "node",
            id: id(l0),
            labels: labels(l0),
        },
        {
            type: "node",
            id: id(l1),
            labels: labels(l1)
        }
    ] as nodes, 
    [
        { 
            startNodeId: ID(startNode(r)),
            endNodeId: ID(endNode(r)), 
            relType: type(r)
        }
    ] as relationship
```

I came accross this example on the forum which is close to what I want:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)=#
RETURN EXTRACT(key IN keys(n) | {key: key, value: n[key]})
```

This results in the following:

> [{"key":"name","value":"Test Node 1"}]

where as I want to have just

> [{"name":"Test Node 1"}]

I am using the KOA-NEO4J library so connecting to Neo4j over Bolt if that makes any difference.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher itself does not allow for dynamically creating the key of a map, however you can use the [APOC function](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) [`apoc.map.fromPairs`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions) to accomplish this. So your example above becomes:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = #
apoc.map.fromPairs([key IN keys(n) | [key, n[key]]])
```

And your larger query becomes:

```
MATCH (l0) -[r]-> (l1)
WHERE ID(l0) = 1
RETURN 
    [
        {
            type: "node",
            id: id(l0),
            labels: labels(l0),
            props: apoc.map.fromPairs([key IN keys(l0) | [key, l0[key]]])
        },
        {
            type: "node",
            id: id(l1),
            labels: labels(l1),
            props: apoc.map.fromPairs([key IN keys(l1) | [key, l1[key]]])
        }
    ] as nodes, 
    [
        { 
            startNodeId: ID(startNode(r)),
            endNodeId: ID(endNode(r)), 
            relType: type(r)
        }
    ] as relationship
```